# RewriteRule fails to execute

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've written a rewrite rule to modify this:

```
https://www.mydomain.com/template.php?staticPage=product.php&code=12345&title=product%20name%20and%description
```

to this:

```
https://www.mydomain.com/product.php/12345/product%20name%20and%20description.html
```

Here's the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /LG_Template.php?staticPage=$1&code=$2&title=$3 [L]
```

And here it is in context with the rest of the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule (^includes/.*)                  $1                          [L]
RewriteRule (^static/.*)                    $1                          [L]
RewriteRule ^Topic\ Pages/([^/\.]+)\.htm$   /category.php?oldname=$1    [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)\.htm$                /template.php?staticPage=product.php&code=$1    [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)\.html$               /template.php?staticPage=product.php&code=$1    [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$                         /template.php?staticPage=$1&code=$2&title=$3 [L]
```

The problem is no rewrite is occurring. I've tried a couple of different options directives at the beginning of the .htaccess I found in posts of similar problems, for example:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews
```

Neither of these seems to have any effect on the problem. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: What URL are you going to and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Reread the first two lines. I want to rewrite my non-SEO friendly URL to a friendly version using RewriteRule. The old URL and the desired replacement are in the first couple of lines of my original post.

Comment: I understand, just trying to get an idea of what the problem is. The rules you have **only** affect URL's that look like: `https://www.mydomain.com/product.php/12345/product%20name%20and%20description.html`

Comment: Yes, but that should be the output rather than the input. That is, what you have is my desired result.

Comment: @user1780242: What happens when you enter: `https://www.mydomain.com/product.php/12345/product%20name%20and%20description.html` in browser?

Comment: The page displays, although it lacks CSS. Do I have something coded backwards?

Comment: css can be taken care of. But what is the main problem then? Isn't this the URL you want in browser to appear?

Comment: Okay -- I get it. My expectations of what RewriteRule is doing are all skewed. I'm afraid I misunderstood the process. So, what I need to do is reformat my link presentation on the site so that what I'm presenting matches the desired link.

Comment: So why would the CSS vanish?

Comment: You're using relative links, the URL base changes when you have stuff like `/12345/` in the URL

Comment: Okay, so I just need to set the CSS link to an absolute link?

Comment: I think I have a much better understanding of what RewriteRule is doing now. Thanks in abundance for your help.